# Why the bar are not aligned the y axis

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I work with [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) to display sensor measures. I use a 
[multi axis solution](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/multi-axis.html).
What I am trying to do is to have line for humidity and and bar rain gauge sensor.
The problem I do have, the lines are well displayed, but the bar are staggered.
[Here is an example of my issue](http://www.smart-idea.io/perrieres/). Select "Station2 (Rangée 27)" and Look at the "Humidité du sol". You also can look at "Temperature" grahp. 
As you can see the bar are not aligned to the lines but there
I really spent a lot of time to understand why and to find a mistake and your help will be appreciate.

From your browser, you can see what return get_measures.php. I add a console.log()

```
console.log("Temperature Success:",data);
console.log("Moisture Success:",data);
```

Here is my code:
(For temperature, the code is almost the same. For temperature, I do not specify the parameter y-axis-0 and y-axis-1 and I do not have two y axis on config_multiAxies(data))

the function get_moisture is working fine and I do not think that the problem come from here. That function send parameter to get_measures.php which retourn a json format data for chartsjs. I pasted it for information. **Scroll to config_multiAxies(data)** , next code where I configure the chart.

```
function get_moisture(para){
    //console.log("get_gauge:",para);

    return $.ajax({
        url: 'include/get_measures.php', 
        type: 'POST',
        data:'type[]=1&type[]=8&y-axis-0=1&y-axis-1=8&'+para, 
        //data:'type[]=1&y-axis-1=1&'+para, 
        //data:'type[]=1&'+para,                                  // data: { pond: pond, from: from, to: to },
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',

    // xhr For testing
       xhr: function () {
        var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        xhr.onprogress = function e() {
            // For downloads
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                console.log("Download ", e.loaded / e.total);
            }
        };
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
            // For uploads
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                //console.log("Upload: ", e.loaded / e.total);
                //$("#loading").show(1);
            }
        };
        return xhr;
    },

        error: function (request, error) {
               console.log("Error......263");
               console.log(request.responseText);     
        },
        success: function (data) {   

            if(data.length <= 0)
            {
            }
            else
            {  
                console.log("Moisture Success:",data);

               // $("#loading").hide(1);
                /*
                if(mychart!=null){
                    mychart.destroy();
                    console.log("NOT NULL DES");
                }
                */

                /* CHECK THIS on consolelog*/
                //if(mychart!=null){
                    //var mCountainer = document.getElementById('moistureContainer');
                    //mCountainer.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
                    $('#moisture').remove();
                    $('#moistureContainer').append('<canvas id="moisture"><canvas>');
                //}


                var ctx = document.getElementById("moisture").getContext('2d');;
                var conf_moisture = config_multiAxies(data);
                mychart = new Chart(ctx, conf_moisture);
/*
                if(mychart!=null){
                    console.log("destroy");
                    mychart.destroy();
                    mychart = new Chart(ctx, conf_moisture);
                }
                */



            }
        }
    });

}
```

config_multiAxies(data)

```
function config_multiAxies(data) {

    var nb_measures=0;
    for(var i= 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        nb_measures = nb_measures + data[i].datasets.data.length;
    }
    //console.log("Number of measures:",nb_measures);


    var data_m_time = [];
    var data_measure_unit = []; 


    //var datas=[];
    var unit;
    var station;
    var datasets = [];


    data_station_name = "No data";
    for(var d= 0; d < data.length; d++)
    {
        if(data[d]['datasets']['yAxisID']=='y-axis-0')
        {
            data_measure_unit[0] = data[d]['unit'];
        }
        if(data[d]['datasets']['yAxisID']=='y-axis-1')
        {
            data_measure_unit[1] = data[d]['unit'];
        }
        //data_measure_unit[d] = data[d]['unit'];

        data_station_name = data[d]['station'];
        datasets.push(data[d]['datasets']);

        data_m_time = data[d]['time'];
    }




   // var progress = document.getElementById('animationProgress');

    return {
               type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: data_m_time,  
                    datasets: datasets 
                },

                options: {
                    title:{
                        display:true,
                        text: data_station_name[0].toUpperCase() + data_station_name.slice(1).toLowerCase() 
                        //text:'toto'
                    },


                    animation: {

                        duration: 50
                    },



                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio:false,

                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: true,
                    },

                    hover: {
                        mode: 'nearest',
                        intersect: true
                    },


                    scales: {

                        xAxes: [{
                            type: 'time',
                            display: true,
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Temps (UTC)'
                            },
                            time: {
                                unit: 'day',
                                unitStepSize: 1,
                                displayFormats: {
                                    'day': 'DD MMM YY'
                                }
                            }       
                        }],

                        yAxes: [{
                            type: 'linear', // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                            display: true,

                            position: 'left',
                            id: 'y-axis-0',
                            /*
                            ticks: {
                                maxTicksLimit: 10,
                                suggestedMax: 200,
                                beginAtZero: true
                            },
                            */

                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                //labelString: data_measure_unit //[''] // meter or unit
                                labelString: data_measure_unit[0]
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                drawOnChartArea: true, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'linear', // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                            display: true,


                            position: 'right',
                            id: 'y-axis-1',

                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: data_measure_unit[1]
                            },

                                // grid line settings
                            gridLines: {
                                drawOnChartArea: false, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
                            }

                        }],
                    } // End scale
                }  // End option
            };

}
```

I would really appreciate any tips and hints in order to have the bar well aligned to the lines. Feel you free to ask additionnal information

**EDIT:**
I just discovered (for temperature) if I unactive the sensor which is reprented by the line, the bar are well display, if the bar are showed "alone". It's the mix of line and bar which "shift" the bar

Comment: Reduce your code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the bug. In current form your question requires a large amount of time to understand the issue. Which makes your question **a)** difficult to understand and answer, **b)** unlikely to help other users with a similar issue. Adding a [mcve] in the question itself shows respect for other users and their time.

Comment: The live project doesn't count as **mcve** because: **a)** it's not *minimal* and **b)** once an answer is provided you'll change it and it will no longer be relevant for the question, making your question no longer helpful for others. You want your question to be as useful for others as possible, as it largely increases the chances of getting it answered.

Comment: Hello Thank for your reply. I simplified the question as both code are similiar. Then I asked my question regarding moisture. Also, the function get_moisture() is working fine. I pasted it for information. The problem come from config_multiAxies(data) where I configure the charts. I hope you cna help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess, I localised the problem
by commenting those line

```
/*,
time: {
  unit: 'day',
  unitStepSize: 1,
  displayFormats: {
    'day': 'DD MMM YY'
  }
}  
*/
```

I have to better investigate but I correct this part of code with works really better

```
time: {
  unit: 'hour',
  stepSize: 1,
  displayFormats: {
    'hour': 'ha'
  }
}
```